# Can't finish transaction in ionic-native/in-app-purchase-2

Tags: javascript, angular, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm developing app with Ionic 4 / Angular 8 / Cordova

I have installed [In App Purchase 2](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2) and setup it. Apple Developer and Sandbox accounts are ok.

Product registration is ok:

```
registerProduct() {
    this.iap.verbosity = this.iap.DEBUG;

    this.iap.register({
        id: MONEYCOMBO_KEY,
        type: this.iap.CONSUMABLE
    })

    this.registerHandlersForPurchase(MONEYCOMBO_KEY)

    this.product = this.iap.get(MONEYCOMBO_KEY)

    this.iap.refresh()

    this.iap.when(MONEYCOMBO_KEY).updated((p) => {
        this.product = p
        this.title = p.title
        this.price = p.price
    })
}
```

Event handlers:

```
registerHandlersForPurchase(productId) {
    let self = this.iap;

    this.iap.when(productId).updated(function (product) {
        if (product.loaded && product.valid && product.state === self.APPROVED && product.transaction != null) {
            product.finish();
        }
    });

    this.iap.when(productId).registered((product: IAPProduct) => {
        // alert(` owned ${product.owned}`);
    });

    this.iap.when(productId).owned((product: IAPProduct) => {
        console.error('finished')
        product.finish();
    });

    this.iap.when(productId).approved((product: IAPProduct) => {
        // alert('approved');
        product.finish();
    });

    this.iap.when(productId).refunded((product: IAPProduct) => {
        // alert('refunded');
    });

    this.iap.when(productId).expired((product: IAPProduct) => {
        // alert('expired');
    });
}
```

Purchase method:

```
buyMoneyCombo(form: NgForm) {
    this.registerHandlersForPurchase(MONEYCOMBO_KEY)
    this.date = form.value.date
    this.iap.order(MONEYCOMBO_KEY)
    this.iap.refresh()
}
```

**The problem:**

Console says:

```
"InAppPurchase[js]: product test has a transaction in progress: 1000000628239595"
```

Transaction cannot be finished. Why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, after a weeks researching, I found the solution.

And there is no problem: 
Message from Apple is displaying after transaction is finished:

```
"InAppPurchase[js]: product test has a transaction in progress: 1000000628239595"
```

And all purchase logic must be declared inside:

```
this.iap.when(MONEYCOMBO_KEY).approved((product: IAPProduct) => {
        product.finish()
        this.getMoney()
    })
```

Comment: Your answer saved my life! Thank you so much